# Android - Save Game - Text File

Tags: java, android

My question is, how do I make a save file using a text file. I want to be able to save the game and to load even after the phone has been restarted.

So what I'm asking is how to make a save file using text file.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

ImageButton Button,Button2,Button3,Button4,Button5,Button6,Button7,Button8,Button9,Button10;
long count = 0;
MediaPlayer mp, mp_pilla,mp_slua;
@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final TextView textview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView);
    mp = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.nyaaw);
    mp_pilla = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.pillabli);
    mp_slua = MediaPlayer.create(MainActivity.this, R.raw.slua);
    Button = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    Button2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton2);
    Button3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton3);
    Button4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton4);
    Button5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton5);
    Button6 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton6);
    Button7 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton7);
    Button8 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton8);
    Button9 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton9);
    Button10 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton10);

    textview.setText("0");


    ImageButton buttonsak = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton);
    ImageButton buttonsak2 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton2);
    ImageButton buttonsak3 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton3);
    ImageButton buttonsak4 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton4);
    ImageButton buttonsak5 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton5);
    ImageButton buttonsak6 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton6);
    ImageButton buttonsak7 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton7);
    ImageButton buttonsak8 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton8);
    ImageButton buttonsak9 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton9);
    ImageButton buttonsak10 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.myButton10);

    View.OnClickListener clicker = new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {
            switch (v.getId()) {
                case R.id.myButton:
                    count++;
                    mp.start();
                    textview.setText("" + count);
                    break;
                case R.id.myButton2:
                    if (count >= 50) {
                        count += 5;
                        mp_slua.start();
                        textview.setText("" + count);
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.myButton3:
                    if (count >= 100) {
                        count += 10;
                        mp_pilla.start();
                        textview.setText("" + count);
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.myButton4:
                    if (count >= 500) {
                        count += 20;
                        mp_slua.start();
                        textview.setText("" + count);
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.myButton5:
                    if (count >= 2000) {
                        count += 50;
                        mp_slua.start();
                        textview.setText("" + count);
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.myButton6:
                    if (count >= 5000) {
                        count += 100;
                        mp.start();
                        textview.setText("" + count);
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.myButton7:
                    if (count >= 10000) {
                        count += 200;
                        mp_slua.start();
                        textview.setText("" + count);
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.myButton8:
                    if (count >= 30000) {
                        count += 500;
                        mp_pilla.start();
                        textview.setText("" + count);
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.myButton9:
                    if (count >= 100000) {
                        count += 1000;
                        mp.start();
                        textview.setText("" + count);
                    }
                    break;
                case R.id.myButton10:
                    if (count >= 250000) {
                        count += 2500;
                        mp_pilla.start();
                        textview.setText("" + count);
                    }
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }
    };

    buttonsak.setOnClickListener(clicker);
    buttonsak2.setOnClickListener(clicker);
    buttonsak3.setOnClickListener(clicker);
    buttonsak4.setOnClickListener(clicker);
    buttonsak5.setOnClickListener(clicker);
    buttonsak6.setOnClickListener(clicker);
    buttonsak7.setOnClickListener(clicker);
    buttonsak8.setOnClickListener(clicker);
    buttonsak9.setOnClickListener(clicker);
    buttonsak10.setOnClickListener(clicker);
}
```

Comment: Why not use SharedPreferences?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use SharePreference to save data like this:

```
SharedPreferences.Editor editor = getSharedPreferences(SAVE_GAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit();
editor.putString("game", "saved");
editor.commit();
```

and get the info like this:

```
SharedPreferences prefs = getSharedPreferences(SAVE_GAME, MODE_PRIVATE); 
String restoredText = prefs.getString("game", null);
if (restoredText != null) {
String name = prefs.getString("game", "state");// "state" is the default value.
}
```

Comment: How do I implement it to my code? and do I need a text file or is it internal stoage?

Comment: Copy and past that code inside your Activity, Fragment, etc onCreate... SharedPreference have an internal storage for its own and it keeps there till the user delete the app. The data keeps even if the user update the app.

Comment: When I paste the code in, I import 1 class but I still have error. http://imgur.com/jIMZz8Z check link below. How do I fix that?

Comment: SAVE_GAME is just a String TAG. Use any string there. Over: @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) { put this: private String SAVE_GAME = "game";

Comment: I did all that, but the game does not save. I get like 10 points and then I restart the phone and the game still resets.

Comment: lol... you don't have to simple copy and paste my code. I don't know you variables. You must save the value over editor.putString("game", "saved"); of editor.putString("game", "saved"); or editor.putInt("game", 1); if you want to save an int. (1 is an example... save your actual int there) also... getInt would be the one you need is you're using int value but you must keep the value key "game" to get the same value.

Comment: Something like this http://imgur.com/z5bAi7D? and you have my code at the top of the page.

Comment: if you want to save an int... save an int... you're saving a String and then trying to get an int value. The first part would be: editor.putInt("game", 1); (Remember! 1 is just an example... 1 is just an int and you should save the actual int value of the points. To GET the points back, use prefs.getInt("game", 1); // Again, 1 is just an example

Answer (score 1):

As @Mariano said: SharedPreferences is a good place to save things. The advantage of SharedPreferences is that it doesn't require any additional permissions.

There are other choices though, depending on your needs. You can write to external storage (which requires the WRITE_EXTERNAL) permission and perhaps much more interesting for you is using the [service that Google provides](https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/savedgames) for saving game state. There are some nice examples on there for you to follow.